# How to align bottom "row" in flex box without affecting the others?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a problem. I have a table which I have implemented in flexbox. I want to make the bottom "row" aligned, without affecting the spacing of the other rows. (I put "row" in quotes because technically it's not rows, it's the last cell in three different columns)

Here's a screenshot of what I want to achieve:
[image: design I am trying to implement]

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/alexbfree/oodo6nxp/) is a JSFiddle of what I have so far. I thought maybe this bit would do it but it seems not:

```
div.new-region-page div.three-col-buys a.read-more {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

I have two main problems - getting the "See more" cells to align, and extending the vertical borders to the same length across all columns.

It's not an option to use flex rows instead of flex columns because of the way this has to collapse responsively in mobile.

Hope someone can advise how I can achieve this with flexbox. I tried various flex attributes with little success.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the columns container (#top-buys) to display:flex; to get all 3 columns the same height.

Once you do that you can adjust your column contents so they aren't all spread out from the space-between setting

If you add flex-grow:0; to the div.new-region-page a.read-more it will push it to the bottom.

Comment: I just tried your approach; while the a.read-more cell does expand to fill the vertical space, the text within is still top-aligned instead of bottom-aligned?

Comment: Thanks so much for spending time helping me out here. That's certainly better, but it doesn't match the design I'm aiming for. I need the top rows to be the same row height, top aligned, then a large gap, then the bottom row to have that same row height as the top ones but be bottom aligned.

Comment: maybe i need to have a blank "filler" cell or something

Comment: I've cracked it! Needed to remove `justify-content:space-between` from the column, and add `flex-grow:1` to the final "cell" above the read-more in each column so that it would stretch to fill available space. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, that helped me solve it! 

Here's my solution
https://jsfiddle.net/alexbfree/oodo6nxp/5/